# How do I set the alarm in Chrome.alarms.create to run once a day?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have some data in my chrome extension app and I want to reset that to 0 every day at 5am local time.

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  chrome.storage.sync.set({ number: 0 }, function() {
  console.log('Wormhole Escaper installed.')
  console.log('The number is set to 0.')

  // I want to create an alarm here to run everyday at 5am?
  chrome.alarms.create('reset', { when: 5166000000 })
})
```

How could I set the when value or how do I create the alarm so that everyday at 5am it runs some code to reset the number to 0 again?

Comment: Use the standard js `Date` object methods to calculate tomorrow's 5am both in onInstalled and in onAlarm callbacks. Then specify it e.g. `when: Number(yourdate)`.

Comment: @wOxxOm how do I calculate tomorrow's 5am? Do I get Date.now() + something? What would be that something?

Comment: See the  documentation for Date. Something like d=new Date; addDay=d.getHours()>=5; d.setHours(5,0,0); d.setFullYear(year , month, date + addDay) where year, month, date are retrieved using the corresponding d.getxxxx